# Installing Reporting Services - Native (SQL Server 2014) error

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2014, ssrs-2014

When I try to install `Reporing Services` on existing instance in `SQL Server` I receive the following error:
[image]

I've tried to do steps described here (http://lokna.no/?p=1180), but it didn't help. How can I solve problem and install `Reporting Services` successfully?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but uninstalling Avast helped. Thanks to this post https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b6533a3a-f215-4d8c-bef9-c8dcdbe253bd/sql-server-2014-on-windows-81-setup-failure-cwindowstemp-folder?referrer=http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b6533a3a-f215-4d8c-bef9-c8dcdbe253bd/sql-server-2014-on-windows-81-setup-failure-cwindowstemp-folder?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade